# How to generate unix timestamp in C++?

Tags: c++, time, timestamp

I get the **second, minute, hour, day, month and year** as single values from my application and need to generate from this values a unix timestamp.

I've only found solutions how to get directly a timestamp with C functions.

How do I generate a unix timestamp with the given values in C++?

Comment: Read the documentation for [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/), it does what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use `std::mktime`, a C library function also available in the C++ standard library:

```
#include <ctime>

std::tm tm;
tm.tm_sec = seconds;
tm.tm_min = minutes;
tm.tm_hour = hours;
tm.tm_mday = day;
tm.tm_mon = month - 1;    // Assuming your month represents Jan with 1
tm.tm_year = year - 1900; // Assuming your year is the AD year number

std::time_t time = std::mktime(&tm);
```

or, for a more C++ flavour, use a third-party library such as Boost.DateTime's [Gregorian date system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html).

Comment: boot is unfortunately no option. so i have to work with the C-lib.
thanks!

Comment: in most cases it will work, but [documentation says that this is undefined behavior](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/)!